# How to append expression variable on ng-repeat in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to append expression variable on  ng-repeat in Angularjs

My code:

```
<div class="col-md-9" ng-controller="AddOrderController">       
              <div class="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel" ng-repeat="t in [1,2]">       
                   <div class="item" ng-repeat="d in datas.item{{t}}" >
                      <imagedata value="d"></imagedata>
                  </div> 
              </div>
        </div>
```

Error this line:  ng-repeat="d in datas.item{{t}}"

i have data.items1, data.item2  json data

how to declare datas.item{{t}} ?

Comment: Interesting post. However, why don't you change the data.items1 and data.items2 attributes into an array instead (That is: data.items = [{value: 'foo'}, {value:'bar'}])? From my perspective that's a cleaner solution for your approach... right?

Comment: no . because i am using  {
  item1:["owl1.jpg","owl2.jpg","owl3.jpg","owl4.jpg"],
  item2:["owl2.jpg","owl2.jpg","owl2.jpg","owl2.jpg"]
   };

Comment: @Bouncing Bit.. can you tell me? how to declare multiple elements in one key?  datats={ item1:["owl1.jpg","owl2.jpg","owl3.jpg","owl4.jpg"] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use an expression in this case, but you don't need to because the `t` variable is already available to you.  just use `ng-repeat="d in datas['item' + t]"`

If this ng-repeat is throwing `Duplicate Key in Repeater`, you may have to modify it slightly to be `ng-repeat="d in datas['item' + t] track by $index"`

Comment: sorry just looked again and realized you need the array syntax here.

Comment: can you help me?  show this Error:      error:dupes
Duplicate Key in Repeater.

Comment: one help  can you tell me? how to declare multiple elements in one key? i am using this datas={ item1:["owl1.jpg","owl2.jpg","owl3.jpg","owl4.jpg"] } is it fine ?

Comment: I don't really see a problem with that... there are other ways you can structure the data, but it's not really easy to make recommendations for alternatives without seeing all the use cases.

Comment: ok. i think datas={ item1:["owl1.jpg","owl2.jpg","owl3.jpg","owl4.jpg"] ,                                         item2:["owl1.jpg","owl2.jpg","owl3.jpg","owl4.jpg"] } it is fine.. because one key multiple datas

Answer (score 1):

How about `ng-repeat="d in datas['item'+t]"`?

Comment: can you help me?  show this Error:      error:dupes
Duplicate Key in Repeater.

Comment: http://www.anujgakhar.com/2013/06/15/duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed-in-angularjs/ - you probably have duplicate values in your datas.item1 or datas.item2 array. Try adding ``track by $index`` at the end of your ngRepeat expression.

Comment: thanks @jlowcs. it is working +1           .                                                  one help  can you tell me? how to declare multiple elements in one key? i am using this datas={ item1:["owl1.jpg","owl2.jpg","owl3.jpg","owl4.jpg"] } is it fine ?